# How to fix undefined operation in Dart sass?

Tags: css, sass

I'm looking to set some variables in bulma. Using dart sass (1.45.1 compiled with dart2js 2.15.1) results in an 'Undefined operation' error

```
Error: Undefined operation "min(1216px, 100vw) - 64px".
   ╷
20 │       max-width: min($widescreen, $container-max-width) - $container-offset
```

The bulma source is included in the primary sass file

```
@use 'menu-large'
@use 'hero'


@import "../../../../libraries/node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass"
```

Why the error on 'min'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min()` function returns a px value, your value is incompatible with subtraction. You cannot subtract other units than px.

You can convert the value of $container-offset to px before:

```
$offset-in-px: $container-offset / ($widescreen / 100);
max-width: min($widescreen, $container-max-width) - $offset-in-px * 1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set to px units rather than using vw:

```
$container-max-width: 1400px
```

Altering the bulma framework is not desirable. MIN() MAX() Wrapping the value doesn't work "#{1200px}".